# After trying a long not able to provide space between 2 card view elements inside a recycler view for both horizontal and vertical

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I want to add some space between 2 cards in both the horizontal recycler view and the vert recycler view but not able to add tried everything but won't getting a sol as u can see in the below image For horizontal both the cards are over each other.

[image: Dont want to override each other]

My XML code in which I had defined recycler view Both hor. and ver.  :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/AppBackground">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/AppBackground">

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>


    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nestedsview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/appBar">


        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/constraint"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/playfair_display_bold_italic"
                android:text="Looking for a delecious cake?"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linear"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/recyclerViewHorizontal"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/playfair_display_bold_italic"
                    android:text="More"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="200dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                    android:text="Button"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="266dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerViewHorizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView6"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.526"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linear"
                tools:context=".FirstActivity">

            </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/playfair_display_bold_italic"
                android:text="Best Selling"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/recyclerViewVertical"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/recyclerViewHorizontal" />

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

                android:id="@+id/recyclerViewVertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="20dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView6"
                tools:context=".FirstActivity"

                >

            </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>


        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

My Xml Code for card :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="20dp"
    >

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="220dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/CardColor"
        app:cardCornerRadius="25sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/constraint"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@color/CardColor"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:foregroundGravity="center_horizontal"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/playfair_display_bold_italic"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Great"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewForPieceInfo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/playfair_display_bold_italic"
                android:text="Ram"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewforPrice"
                android:text="Shyam"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/playfair_display_bold_italic"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewForPieceInfo" />

            <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                app:fabSize="mini"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_add_24" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

My recycler view class code:

```
package com.example.cako;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;

public class FirstActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);

        String []x={"Aaran", "Aaren", "Aarez", "Aarman", "Aaron", "Aaron-James", "Aarron", "Aaryan", "Abhinav","Ankit"};
        String []image= {"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c8/Aloo_gobi.jpg/180px-Aloo_gobi.jpg",
                "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c8/Aloo_gobi.jpg/180px-Aloo_gobi.jpg",
                "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d1/Aloo_Tikki_served_with_chutneys.jpg/180px-Aloo_Tikki_served_with_chutneys.jpg",
                "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4f/Aloo_Mattar.jpg/180px-Aloo_Mattar.jpg",
                "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fa/Aloo_Methi_%28Aaloo_Methi%29.JPG/180px-Aloo_Methi_%28Aaloo_Methi%29.JPG",
                "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b0/Spicy_alloo_with_tadka_mirchi.jpg/180px-Spicy_alloo_with_tadka_mirchi.jpg",
                "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c8/Aloo_gobi.jpg/180px-Aloo_gobi.jpg",
                "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c8/Aloo_gobi.jpg/180px-Aloo_gobi.jpg",
                "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d1/Aloo_Tikki_served_with_chutneys.jpg/180px-Aloo_Tikki_served_with_chutneys.jpg",
                "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4f/Aloo_Mattar.jpg/180px-Aloo_Mattar.jpg"
        };

        Toolbar toolbar=findViewById(R.id.toolbar) ;
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        RecyclerView horizontalrecyclerView =(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewHorizontal);
        horizontalrecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false));
        horizontalrecyclerView.setAdapter(new RecyclerVview(this,x,image));

        RecyclerView verticalrecyclerView =(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewVertical);
        verticalrecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this,2));
        verticalrecyclerView.setAdapter(new RecyclerVview(this,x,image));
    }
}

class RecyclerVview extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerVview.Holder>{
    Activity co;
    String[] name;
    String[] image;

    public RecyclerVview(Context applicationContext, String[] x, String[] image) {
        co=(Activity)applicationContext;
        name=x;
        this.image=image;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Holder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v=LayoutInflater.from(co).inflate(R.layout.layout_for_horizontal_recyclerview,parent,false);
        return new Holder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final Holder holder, int position) {
        holder.textViewForItemName.setText(name[position]);
        Glide.with(co).load(image[position]).into(holder.image);
        holder.floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(co, "yesWorking", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.i("yes","log");
            }
        });
        holder.textViewForPrice.setText("30$");
        holder.textViewForPieceInfo.setText("Single Piece Only.");
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return name.length;
    }

    public class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        ImageView image;
        TextView textViewForItemName;
        FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton;
        TextView textViewForPrice;
        TextView textViewForPieceInfo;

        public Holder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            image=itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            textViewForItemName=itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
            floatingActionButton=itemView.findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButton);
            textViewForPieceInfo=itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewForPieceInfo);
            textViewForPrice=itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewforPrice);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add margin for the `CarView` layout and inside the ContraintLayout
and Use this for your card.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:margin="8dp"
    >

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="220dp"
        android:margin="8dp"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/CardColor"
        app:cardCornerRadius="25sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/constraint"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@color/CardColor"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:foregroundGravity="center_horizontal"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/playfair_display_bold_italic"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Great"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewForPieceInfo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/playfair_display_bold_italic"
                android:text="Ram"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewforPrice"
                android:text="Shyam"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/playfair_display_bold_italic"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewForPieceInfo" />

            <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                app:fabSize="mini"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_add_24" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```